# Alert before sending an email with a blank Bcc field

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

In the same way Microsoft Outlook will pop up an alert if you try to send an email with the To field left blank, or try to send a calendar invite with the Location field blank, I want an alert that comes up if I have left the Bcc field blank. Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: This could be done with an Outlook add-on.  You might even be able to do a VBA script that checks for it.

Answer (score 1):

put this vba in your `thisoutlooksession` module and adjust your **macro settings accordingly**

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


End Sub

Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)


Dim prompt As String
prompt = "The BCC Field is empty!"



If Item.BCC = "" Then


    If msgbox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "BCC Field") = vbNo Then
    Cancel = True
    End If
 End If

End Sub
```